# Getting database output correct way in block

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, href

I want to make a kind of forum with php (pdo) now I can get the data out of the database like you can see with the 2 items in the picture down below (de 2 dots with text) now I want the `<H5>` tagg to be the things on the dots but I have no clue how to do that.

[image: This is what I have right now with this code]

What I want

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="well dash-box">
      <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" aria-hidden="true"></span> Inspiratie</h2>
       <h5>Tips en inspiratie om jou en je business een boost te geven, dit kan van groot belang zijn.</h5>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="well dash-box">
          <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12</h2>
           <h5><a href="https://google.nl"> hoi</a></h5>
          <?php
             $toppics = $app->get_topics();
             $i = 4;
             foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
             echo '<li><a href="#section' . $i++ . '">' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</a></li>';
             }
          ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is how the database looks like] It takes the column "onderwerp" out of the database and I want those to be the `<H5>`tags

Comment: `echo '<li><h5><a href="#section' . $i++ . '">' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</a></h5></li>';` try that

Comment: @dean nope it only adds a break after the dots

Comment: wait you want to add `<h5>` to only `.$i++. `  ?

Comment: @dean as you can see on the picture I got several `<H5>` tags and I want those to get it out of the database, I want the "nieuws & events" to be the thing after the first dot and the "stel je voor" to be the second dot

Comment: This isn't making much sense to me. Maybe replace `li` with `h5` ? Would help if you had a mockup of what you wanted. And we cannot "see H5 tags" on the image... tags are just element blocks that define something.

Comment: @IncredibleHat The `<H5>`tags are the `Nieuws & Events, Stel je voor , Inspiration ect ect ` and I want each of those to get the title out of the database

Comment: do you have the title saved in the DB, i really don't understand

Comment: @dean changed the questions

Comment: the dots are caused by `<li></li>`tag.  now create a class on that `<li class="lii"></li>` Then add this code to your css file `.lii{ list-style: none;}` the dot will go away. let me hope  you have access to all the files

Comment: The dots are not the problem!!  I want the H5  tags to change to the things out of the database....

Comment: @youarewelkommmornott you want `<HTML>tag..` to change to what? cant you `echo` the entire code?

Comment: @dean Please read what I told you before explained it for like 3 times. I want the <H5> TAGS (the titles) to change to the things in "onderwerp" so I want Nieuws & Events to change to `Testen Forum' and the other on to the other thing out the database